# PuPHPet Vagrant Debian - Won't change provisioned Node.js version

Tags: node.js, vagrant, debian, puphpet

I want to change the Node.js version provisioned with my custom machine (debian75-x64) from v0.12.15 to v4.5.0. The `config.yml` originally was:

```
nodejs:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '0.12'
    npm_packages:
        - bower
        - gulp
        - grunt-cli
        - browser-sync
```

and I changed it to:

```
nodejs:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '4'
    npm_packages:
        - bower
        - gulp
        - grunt-cli
        - browser-sync
```

then ran `vagrant provision`, and check if a new node version has been installed. Unfortunately I keep getting

```
$ node --version
v0.12.15
```

no matter restarting the machine and provisioning again.
Am I missing to do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citing Juan in https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/2420:

> Inside your VM delete /.puphpet-stuff/nodesource and try again.

It worked.